# How to realloc across multiple threads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, malloc, realloc

I have created a list of an undefined size using malloc which keeps track of threads and their data. However, if I realloc while the threads are still running, they are no longer able to save their data as the struct's memory location has changed. My project is constantly adding/subtracting threads so I need realloc.

Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct option_data {
    char* contract[3];
} option_data;

typedef struct thread_data {
    char* thread;
} thread_data;

DWORD WINAPI optionSymbol(void* dat) {
    option_data* data = (option_data*)dat;
    data->contract[0] = 6;
    data->contract[1] = 7;
    data->contract[2] = 5;
    return 0;
}

int create_thread(void* data, void* dat2) {
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, optionSymbol, data, 0, NULL);
    thread_data* t_data = (thread_data*)dat2;
    t_data->thread = thread;
    return 0;
}

void reallocation(lista, sizeOfList)
{
    char** list = lista;
    char* listThingy = realloc(*list, sizeOfList * sizeof * list);
    if (listThingy == NULL)
        free(listThingy);
    else
        *list = listThingy;
}

int getChains(void)
{
    option_data* optionDataList = malloc(sizeof(option_data));
    thread_data* threadDataList = malloc(sizeof(thread_data));
    create_thread(&optionDataList[0], &threadDataList[0]);
    //reallocation(&optionDataList, 2)
    //reallocation(*threadDataList, 2) <-- The code returns unpredictably when un-noting these two lines.
    create_thread(&optionDataList[0], &threadDataList[0]);
    WaitForSingleObject(threadDataList[0].thread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(threadDataList[0].thread);
    printf("%i", optionDataList[0].contract[0]);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    getChains();
    return 0;
}
```

How would I realloc without changing the original memory location of the structs or send the new memory location to the threads?

Comment: This might be a case where a linked list is actually easier (and maybe even faster).

Comment: You can not realloc and have a guarantee of unchanged location. Use a different data structure. (perhaps list?)

Comment: @PaulG. Do you mean something like 'option_data data[2]'? The problem with this is you must have a predefined size, which lead me to using 'option_data* optionDataList = malloc(sizeof(option_data));' in the first place.

Comment: @SergeyA The reason I'm using malloc instead of a list is that I need an undefined size.

Comment: No a linked list is not a language feature in C (it is part of the standard library in C++). You can build one in C by having a struct of a value and a pointer to the next element. You will easily find examples online. Looping through a linked list and random access are very slow. But if mainly every thread has its own node and the number of threads is fluctuating as you say, it might be faster to allocate/free single nodes than reallocating that array.

Comment: If it is important to have something sequential in memory, you might want to just allocate a big array once and just increment/decrement a variable saying were the array "ends" at any point in time (like a C++ vector). This idea should be easier to implement in C.

Comment: @I mow hair. - It's no wonder that you get a segmentation fault if you pass `*threadDataList`, an object of type `thread_data`, to a function which expects an argument of type `int` and implicitly converts this to an object of type `char **` - and there are many more type mismatches in the shown code. It's unbelievable that the compiler doesn't tell you that.

Comment: If you are planning to share a data structure across threads, and the data structure is not going to be immutable/unchanged during the time the threads have access to it, then you will need to serialize all accesses to the data structure (both read-only *and* read/write accesses) by locking mutex before accessing the data structure and unlocking it afterwards.  Otherwise you will suffer from race conditions and the resulting undefined behavior (read:  random crashes and/or data corruption)